# Can I point a sub-folder to a different server using nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a very old server that has a legacy application on it that powers a website.
I can't really modify much on this server as it is very old, I am slowly migrating away from it before I decommission it.

I want to server content from another newer server for a specific folder on the website:

```
www.example.com/blog/
```

Is it possible for me to server content for all requests for the /blog sub folder from a different domain by adding a nginx server blog for this rule?

Answer (score 0):

You can define 2 upstreams old_server and new_server and then define 2 location with different [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).

Take a look here:  http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

```
upstream old_server {
    server old_server.example.com:8080;
}
upstream new_server {
    server new_server.example.com:8080;
}
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://old_server;
    }

    location ~* /blog {
        proxy_pass http://new_server;
    } 
}
```

Good Luck!